# Add stylus to a webpack 2 app which has css modules

Tags: webpack, stylus, webpack-2, css-modules

I have a webpack 2 app which uses [css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)

I now just want to start using [stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) as well.

I guess the solution is to update my webpack.config.js:

current webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader'
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'css-loader',
        query: {
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        }
      },

    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin( { filename: 'style.css', allChunks: true }),
  ],
}
```

so into the `rules` array in the config, I added:

```
  {
  test: /\.styl$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader',
    {
      loader: 'stylus-loader',
    },
  ],
},
```

**EDIT: I then added:**

```
var hook = require('css-modules-require-hook');
var stylus = require('stylus');

hook({
  extensions: ['.styl'],
  preprocessCss: function (css, filename) {
    return stylus(css)
      .set('filename', filename)
      .render();
  },
});
```

**to the top of webpack.config.js as per [css-modules-require-hook](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules-require-hook) however I am unsure if the hook is supposed to go at the top of the webpack.config.js file and then if I need to somehow call the hook inside the webpack.config `module.exports`**

I have added one .styl file:

logo/index.styl:

```
.img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 228px;
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
import styles from './index.styl'

function view() {
return (<img className={`${styles.img}`}
              src="src/img/logo_transparent_background.png"
            />)
}
```

The output html inspected in the developer console shows:

```
<img class="undefined" src="src/img/logo_transparent_background.png">
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have `stylus_plugin` installed, but you can't install it because there is no such package in the npm registry. And in fact that was supposed to be an example use of plugins you could use (e.g. [poststylus](https://github.com/seaneking/poststylus)). To be fair that wasn't quite clear from the [stylus-loader Readme](https://github.com/shama/stylus-loader#stylus-plugins) and has just been mentioned in the GitHub issue [Error: Cannot find module 'stylus_plugin' #155](https://github.com/shama/stylus-loader/issues/155#issuecomment-263435090).

So just remove this non-existing plugin and it should work.

## Edit

Now to your other question: **Why do the stylus modules not work?**

Well you need to enable `css-modules` for your `.styl` files as well. And while on that subject you should also only have one `.css` rule and include both `style-loader` and `css-loader` in there, otherwise they will be applied separately, not in sequence. So your `modules.rules` should look like this:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.styl$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
          }
        },
        'stylus-loader'
      ],
    },
  ]
},
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I had to change my question considerably after I removed the plugin so the question is now addressing a different issue (still to do with getting stylus working with css modules through webpack)

Comment: Edited the answer to fix stylus modules, and that hook is not required.

Comment: Thanks a million. Works!!